# event listener wait for action/callback

Tags: typescript, promise, callback

Is it possible to handle an event listener like a callback and wait for its action/return?

Here is the scenario, I load a page and call `initialize()` which renders a div and a button but keeps it hidden. Then I tap a icon which I then display the div and button to make it visible.

When I call `showDivAndButton`, I'm waiting on a Promise or callback for when someone clicks on the rendered button. In this case I'm waiting for the "whats up?"

```
initialize() {
  window.addEventListener('message', async (e) => { if(e.data === 'hello-world') { return "whats up?"; } });
  renderDivAndButton();
}

showDivAndButton() {
  divAndButton.setVisible(true);

  // wait for button to be pressed and return string
}

renderDivAndButton() {
  btn.onclick = { window.postMessage('hello-world', '*'); }
}
```

maybe `async showDivAndButton(): Promise<string> {}` ?

then do something like `let res = await showDivAndButton();`

but it doesn't make sense

Comment: I can't see `showDivAndButton` being called anywhere in the given example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could absolutely write a function using async/await that waits for the message you've posted to be fired (which is triggered by the button). To do that you'll need to wrap your event listener in a promise, like this:

```
async function waitForMessage() {
   return new Promise((accept, reject) => {
      const handler = (event: MessageEvent) => {
         if(event.data === 'hello-world') {
            /**
             * This try catch is important if your handler 
             * does something more complicated that might
             * throw an error. If you don't do this, your
             * awaiting function won't be able to catch that error
             */
            try {
               // More code
               accept("What's up?")
            } catch(error) {
               reject(error)
            }
         }
         window.removeEventListener('message', handler)
      }

      window.addEventListener('message', handler);
   });
}
```

This function can now be awaited exactly as you intend:

```
const message = await waitForMessage()
console.log(message) // "What's up?"
```